# Status bar not changing color in lollipop

Tags: android

I am trying to get the status bar color changed for lollipop. I believe this happens automatically by giving the style in XML

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

But this is not happening in my Nexus 5? I am not sure what could be wrong?

Can somebody help me with this?

Here is the Style.xml file for v21:

```
<style name="Theme.default" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="md_widget_color">@color/bluetext</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orangeText</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/numbertext</item>

    </style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ylg.defaultApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.default" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Ylg_default"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you include the AndroidManifest.xml entry for your activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I have added the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="cp">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="cpd">@color/color_secondary</item>
    <item name="ca">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

---

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: put it in `v21` ? after that use the same `theme` in `manifest` file. for the `<activity` tag.

Comment: Yep. I am already using the theme.. and tried to add this didn't work.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace with

```
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#D11C1C")));
```

For full custamization you can follow this link.
http://www.7solutions.in/2015/07/making-of-custom-action-bar-status-bar.html#more